# What does this mean? $K_n \boxtimes K_n$

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I have to show that $K_n \boxtimes K_n = K_{n^2}$. Where $K_n$ is a complete graph. What does the operator "$\boxtimes$" do?

Comment: When you have a question about notation like that, it's a good idea to say where you found it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book *Handbook of Product Graphs 2nd Edition - Hammack et al.* you can find the following definition:

The strong product of $G$ and $H$ is the graph denoted as $G \boxtimes H$, and defined by

$$ V(G\boxtimes H) = \{(g,h) | g \in V(G) \text{ and } \in V(H) \}. $$
$$ E(G\boxtimes H) = E(G\square H) \cup E(G\times H). $$

[image: Examples of products.]

Answer (score 0):

It's the [Strong product of graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_product_of_graphs)...